# why slice function not working without explicit use of dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

I am learning to use dplyr and came across function slice. I tried to call it with and without explicit dplyr.

It works with explicit calling but gives error when called without dplyr. Can someone guide me what is the source of the error?

As far I know slice function is exclusive to dplyr or it belongs to some other package as well?

```
> library("tidyverse") 
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] faraway_1.0.7       pd.hg.u95av2_3.12.0 DBI_1.0.0           oligo_1.46.0        oligoClasses_1.44.0
 [6] RSQLite_2.1.1       Biostrings_2.50.2   XVector_0.22.0      IRanges_2.16.0      S4Vectors_0.20.1   
[11] ArrayExpress_1.42.0 Biobase_2.42.0      BiocGenerics_0.28.0 bindrcpp_0.2.2      forcats_0.3.0      
[16] stringr_1.3.1       dplyr_0.7.8         purrr_0.2.5         tidyr_0.8.2         tibble_2.0.0       
[21] ggplot2_3.1.0       tidyverse_1.2.1     readr_1.3.1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-137                bitops_1.0-6                matrixStats_0.54.0         
 [4] lubridate_1.7.4             bit64_0.9-7                 httr_1.4.0                 
 [7] GenomeInfoDb_1.18.1         tools_3.5.1                 backports_1.1.3            
[10] utf8_1.1.4                  R6_2.3.0                    affyio_1.52.0              
[13] lazyeval_0.2.1              colorspace_1.3-2            withr_2.1.2                
[16] tidyselect_0.2.5            bit_1.1-14                  curl_3.3                   
[19] compiler_3.5.1              preprocessCore_1.44.0       cli_1.0.1                  
[22] rvest_0.3.2                 xml2_1.2.0                  DelayedArray_0.8.0         
[25] labeling_0.3                scales_1.0.0                digest_0.6.18              
[28] minqa_1.2.4                 pkgconfig_2.0.2             lme4_1.1-19                
[31] limma_3.38.3                rlang_0.3.1                 readxl_1.2.0               
[34] rstudioapi_0.9.0            bindr_0.1.1                 generics_0.0.2             
[37] jsonlite_1.6                BiocParallel_1.16.5         RCurl_1.95-4.11            
[40] magrittr_1.5                GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.0      Matrix_1.2-15              
[43] Rcpp_1.0.0                  munsell_0.5.0               fansi_0.4.0                
[46] stringi_1.2.4               yaml_2.2.0                  MASS_7.3-51.1              
[49] SummarizedExperiment_1.12.0 zlibbioc_1.28.0             plyr_1.8.4                 
[52] grid_3.5.1                  affxparser_1.54.0           blob_1.1.1                 
[55] crayon_1.3.4                lattice_0.20-38             haven_2.0.0                
[58] splines_3.5.1               hms_0.4.2                   pillar_1.3.1               
[61] GenomicRanges_1.34.0        codetools_0.2-16            XML_3.98-1.16              
[64] glue_1.3.0                  BiocManager_1.30.4          modelr_0.1.2               
[67] nloptr_1.2.1                foreach_1.4.4               cellranger_1.1.0           
[70] gtable_0.2.0                assertthat_0.2.0            broom_0.5.1                
[73] ff_2.2-14                   iterators_1.0.10            memoise_1.1.0 

> worldcup %>% dplyr::slice(1:3)


Team   Position Time Shots Passes Tackles Saves player_name

1 Algeria Midfielder   16     0      6       0     0      Abdoun

2   Japan Midfielder  351     0    101      14     0         Abe

3  France   Defender  180     0     91       6     0      Abidal

> worldcup %>% slice(1:3)

Error in .Call2("Rle_constructor", values, lengths, PACKAGE = "S4Vectors") :

  Rle of type 'list' is not supported
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 6):

I think a safer solution might be to use `dplyr::slice` in case you end up needing S4Vectors for something else. Perhaps another package relies on `S4Vectors` or even `S4Vectors::slice` explicitly.

Comment: It should be noted that one can also overwrite the reference to the S4Vectors slice function by using `slice <- dplyr::slice`

Answer (score 5):

`worldcup %>% slice(1:3)` calls `slice` from `S4Vectors` package and not dplyr.

Try doing:

`detach("package:S4Vectors")`

Then run:

`worldcup %>% slice(1:3)`

Comment: many thanks for the quick reply

> detach("package:S4Vectors")
Error: package ‘S4Vectors’ is required by ‘pd.hg.u95av2’ so will not be detached

as you can see I can not detach the "package:S4Vectors" and thus it seems the only way to work around this is to use dplyr::slice()

Comment: yes, that seems more convenient in your case, otherwise remove the other package.

Comment: CuriusScientist, you never call (explicitly in this code) `library(S4Vectors)` or even `library(pd.hg.u95av2)`, how are they in your search path? The package `pd.hg.u95av2` might need `S4Vectors` to be installed, but if it was made correctly then it will not require it to be in the search path. When you start R fresh (nothing listed in `sessionInfo()` attached packages), try loading neither of them or at most the latter, and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: I think a safer solution might be to use `dplyr::slice` in case you end up needing `S4Vectors` for something else (perhaps another packaged depends on it).